# Unable to cast object of type 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope'

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, asp.net-mvc-5, dbcontext

So I am trying to implement my IoC that linked my DBContext class as a Dependency Injection as a ServiceProvider.

I am getting this error when it comes to starting my ASP Core app
So my question is; What am i doing wrong, i tried googling it but i can't really find a solution that way.
I tried asking some of the more elite programmers on my campus but they haven ot specifically worked with ASPnet Core so they don't know if it's because of my casting or because of ASPnet Core

> Application startup exception: System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope' to type 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider'.
>      at Spackk.Startup.Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, IServiceProvider serviceProvider) in F:\Developement\SpackkMVC\Spackk\Spackk\Startup.cs:line 44
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConventionBasedStartup.Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.HostFilteringStartupFilter.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.b__0(IApplicationBuilder app)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.AutoRequestServicesStartupFilter.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.b__0(IApplicationBuilder builder)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.BuildApplication()
>   crit: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[6]
>         Application startup exception
>   System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope' to type 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider'.
>      at Spackk.Startup.Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, IServiceProvider serviceProvider) in F:\Developement\SpackkMVC\Spackk\Spackk\Startup.cs:line 44
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConventionBasedStartup.Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.HostFilteringStartupFilter.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.b__0(IApplicationBuilder app)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.AutoRequestServicesStartupFilter.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.b__0(IApplicationBuilder builder)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.BuildApplication()

This is how the code looks in Startup

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using System;

namespace Spackk
{
    public class Startup
    {
        private readonly string UserGuid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }


        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            //add ApplicationDbContext to DI
            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer("Server=.;Database=SpackkDB;Trusted_Connection;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"));
            services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
            {
                // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
                options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
                options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
            });


            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {

            //Store isntance of the DI Service provider so our application can access iot anywhere
            IocContainer.Provider = (ServiceProvider)serviceProvider;
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseCookiePolicy();

            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
        }
    }
}
```

This is where the the class where the error is happening;

For context i will also provide the IoC/IoCContainer/ApplicationDbContext and the model;

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace Spackk.Models
{
    public class UserModel
    {
        [Key]
        public string Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [MaxLength(255)]
        [Display(Name = "UserName")]
        public string Username { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [MaxLength(255)]
        [Display(Name = "DisplayName")]
        public string DisplayName { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [MaxLength(255)]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Password")]
        public string Password { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [MaxLength(255)]
        [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
        [Display(Name = "Email")]
        public string Email { get; set; }
    }
}
```

ApplicationDbContext

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Spackk.Models;
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace Spackk
{
    public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public string Id { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N");
        public DbSet<UserModel> Users { get; set; }
        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="options"></param>
        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options) : base(options)
        {

        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder mBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(mBuilder);

            mBuilder.Entity<UserModel>().HasIndex(a => a.DisplayName);
        }
    }
}
```

IoC/IoCContainer

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

namespace Spackk
{
    public class IoC
    {

        /// <summary>
        /// The scoped instance of the <see cref="ApplicationDbContext()"/>
        /// </summary>
        public static ApplicationDbContext ApplicationDbContext => IocContainer.Provider.GetService<ApplicationDbContext>();
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// the dependenc injection container making use of the built in .Net Core service provider
    /// </summary>
    public class IocContainer
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// the service provider for the is application
        /// </summary>
        public static ServiceProvider Provider { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: This approach in the tutorial is shown to make you understand how the ApplicationDbContext works and what you can do with it. He never says this is the preferred way of doing this and it is not. Using dependency injection is much better. Additionally, I got the same error, then concluded that they probably changed something and it is actually not that important since no one should ever use it this way anyways.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, the error is explicit and it's fairly obviously failing on this line:

```
IocContainer.Provider = (ServiceProvider)serviceProvider;
```

`serviceProvider` there is an instance of `ServiceProviderEngineScope`, which cannot be cast to `ServiceProvider`. Just because they both implement `IServiceProvider` doesn't mean that you can cast from one to the other implementation.

However, this entire thing is just *wrong*. Like *WRONG*. I wish I could put more emphasis on that. Imagine a 20-ft billboard with flashing LEDs in bright neon red. Either use DI or *don't*, but it's completely wrong to just stuff some static class with some dependency-injected object and then expect to be able to just use that wherever you like.

Comment: hmm, I am following a tutorial on this; so it might be that the way this person is doing it is wrong indeed. I will reflectg on what you said and probably cast it asside.
I wanted to learn more about FluentAPI but it seems that how it's teaching my isn't the right way to do so. Thank you.

Comment: To anyone following the same tutorial: You dont need to make this work, he then deletes it and uses constructor injection instead. This was just to show how he would usually do DI. Hope this saves you several hours of debugging.